# How to get call hierarchy/call graph/caller graph in eclipse for golang (go language)?

Tags: eclipse, go, goclipse

I tried goclipse but that didn't work.

I know eclipse can do that for languages like Java.  Why doesn't it work for go language?

Comment: I don't think the Go plugins supports that.

Comment: BTW you can do that pretty easily with `pprof` outside of Eclipse if you haven't tried it already. this article discusses it: http://blog.golang.org/profiling-go-programs

Comment: This discussion may give you some info: http://grokbase.com/t/gg/goclipse/139t9j3t4p/go-oracle . It's discussing including the Go Oracle tool into Goclipse (The Go oracle tool can give you, amongst other things, the call graph. See http://golang.org/s/oracle-user-manual). It seems that Goclipse should be able to use the XML output, but the author may not be spending much time developing Goclipse any more.

Answer (score 0):

Somebody would need to implement this in goclipse.

[Oracle](http://golang.org/s/oracle-user-manual) can do that, but you need somebody to integrate it with your preferred editor/IDE.

Comment: StarScope (https://rubygems.org/gems/starscope) also provides similar information, though not in as much depth as Oracle. However, StarScope exports to both ctags and cscope formats, so it automatically gets integration with any editor supporting those types.